# ...Find the probability that the first card is a red face card and the second card is a Spade.

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn without replacement from a deck of 52 cards. Find the probability that the *first card* is a **red face card** and the *second card* is a **Spade**.

I'm reading through some notes and they are causing me a litle confusion. My intuition causes me to think that I can take the probability of drawing a red face card (8/52) *assuming an Ace is a face card* and multiply it by the probability of drawing a spade when a red face card has successfully been drawn on the first draw(13/51). I end up with something like .040...; but I'm second guessing myself because these lecture notes are a little confusing. His solution just says 26/52 13/51. No parenthesis, no mathematical operators, just these two ratio right next to each other. Any guidance or clarity would be greatly appreciated.I feel like my intuition is correct; however my intuition has lead me astray on quite a few occasions.

Comment: $26/52 \cdot 13/51$ is correct for a red card, then a spade, but specifying a face card changes things to your solution.

Comment: Lecture notes are often not as carefully prepared as (say) the textbook solutions.  Perhaps whoever wrote up the lecture notes misread the problem.  Certainly with parentheses in the right places we would get the answer to a slightly different problem, but I like your solution to the problem as stated in your Question.